# SQL Server Backup never completes or reports any percentage

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am currently using the code below. I had to increase the timeout in order to stop the disconnect. The database is only 1gb and I'm not sure why this database never backs up.  Any clues?  No error is reported it just doesn't backup

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

public static void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
{
   string conString = string.Format("Server=server;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
   ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(conString);
   con.ConnectTimeout = 70000;
   con.StatementTimeout = 70000;
   Server server = new Server(con);
   Backup source = new Backup();
   source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
   source.Database = "backedupdb";
   BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile+"\\"+source.Database.ToString(), DeviceType.File);
   source.Devices.Add(destination);
   source.Initialize = false;
   source.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
   source.Complete += Backup_Completed;
   source.SqlBackup(server);
   con.Disconnect();
}

private static void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs args)
{
   Console.Clear();
   Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", args.Percent);
}

private static void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Backup completed.");
   Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
}

private static void Restore_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Restore completed.");
   Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
}
```

Comment: \\networkpath\mydrive\backup here

Comment: @Ramhound thats fine, but what i'm trying to explain is once source.SqlBackup(server) occurs it never gets to con.Disconnect(); or even reports a percent, in fact if i dont extend the timeout it will just timeout like nothing is happening

Comment: @Ramhound I just created a test database with 1 table and 1 row, it doesnt even start.  If I backup this database using microsoft management studio its done a backup in 25 seconds

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the debugger? And have you used SQL Profiler to verify that the SQL commands being sent to the server are correct?

Comment: @Pondlife the debugger enters the line source.SqlBackup(server); and thats were it sits, the command is being sent

Comment: @Ramhound okay well lets do this, instead of just saying its flawed show me what would make it work, because i used this http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/  which has been voted as the answer i dont know how many times

Comment: @Ramhound How am I never making the connection, when the connection is timing out?

Comment: And what is the full SQL command? Does it work when you copy and paste it from Profiler into SSMS?

Comment: @Ramhound Then show a better.....

Comment: Perhaps you can get more details if you hook up to the `Information` event.

Comment: The connection string seems to actually be the issue, when using SMO you just want to supply the server name

Comment: @Ramhound To bad you're wrong, you dont have to initalize the connection

Comment: @Mike - As you wish. **I hope you will understand that I removed underhanded response to me from your answer.**  If you don't agree, then just roll the answer back a revision, your underhanded attack is not constructive.

Comment: @Mike - I attmpeted to be constructive. I point out what I thought was a problem. You were not exactly in an accepting feedback mood. I attempted to point out possible flaws in the code that I saw.  You didn't seem to accept that feedback and just wrote it off as noise which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string is the issue in the above example, it does not want a "connectionstring" it simply wants the server name.  The connection does not have to be initialized it will automatically be called.

```
    string conString = string.Format("server");
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(conString);
```